# Cannot send email with Mailjet in Laravel 8

Tags: email, smtp, laravel-8, mailjet

I'm trying to send an email with Laravel 8 using Mailjet SMTP.

I set the SMPT credentials in .env file,I think properly convfigured my Mailjet driver in my app and I created and defined my mailable Class. To do a test I created a new route in my web.php file. But when I go to the route in my navigator, I get the Error :
`Swift_Mailer::__construct(): Argument #1 ($transport) must be of type Swift_Transport, Symfony\Component\Mailer\Bridge\Mailjet\Transport\MailjetApiTransport given, called in C:\xampp\projects\FbAppLlc\FbAppLlc(Prod)\FbAppLlc\teamfb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\MailManager.php on line 152`
Does anyone know about this error and how to fix it ?